# Customize language link in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am coding multi-languages web site with Drupal 7. Does anyone know how can I customize the language links like adding lang. flag, changing color of links and so on?

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

To set the language to a link, use the `language` property inside the [l() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)'s array $options.

Note that, the `language` property does not take language code, instead it takes language object. To get the language object for any enabled languages, you can use the code below.

```
function _return_language_object($langCode)
{ // better to place this code inside your theme's template.php file.
    $languages = language_list(); // see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/7
    return $languages[$langCode];
}
```

Then use the l function to print the link.

```
print l("English Homepage", "", array(
     'language' => _return_language_object("en"),
));
```